# SHAP KernelExplainer AttributeError numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, lime

I've developed a text classifier of the form of python function that can input a np.array of strings (each string is one observation).

```py
def model(vector_of_strins):
     ... # do smthg
     return vec_of_probabilities # like [0.1, 0.23, ..., 0.09]
```

When I try to use `KernelExplainer` from `shap` package like that

```py
test_texts = pd.Series(['text1','text2','text3'])
shap.KernelExplainer(model, test_texts )
```

I receive the following error:

```py
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'find'
```

What can I do about it?

Comment: Can you provide a more clear cut example, so that we can provide you a solution? Meaning, some test data, the classifier? For example, you mention a `vec_of_probabilities` but where does that get used? What model are you using? How would a model work on text and not numbers? Also, can you provide the full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no information about the model function provided, I'm assuming that it iterates the strings and tries to use the `find` method on them to assign probabilities.

The `KernelExplainer` method calls the model function by passing the samples as the first argument, the input array shape is `#samples x #features`. In your case it will be `(1,3)`, so trying to iterate over the array will give you the inner array.

Try to adapt your code to work with 2d arrays. Or in your case to make a quick fix, just iterate over `vector_of_strins[0]`.